# Why tab screen of createMaterialTobTapNavigator is not rendering?

Tags: react-navigation

I'm using createMaterialTopTabNavigator. Inside screen i want top tab navigator. But isn't not showing any screen.

react-native 0.59.9 and react-navigation 3.11.0

````
  {
 ```   TaskListRoute: { screen: Create },
  ```  Register: { screen: List }
  },
  {
  ```  tabBarPosition: "top",
  ```  animationEnabled: false,
   ``` lazy: true,
   ``` swipeEnabled: false
  }
);

I want to render both screen of top tab.
````

Comment: Did you mean the header isn't showing?

Comment: No, thank u . I feature it out. There is little bit change in v3.